# each block in Meteor app not rendering

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, rendering, each

I want to create a little todo list application using the Meteor framework. This is a test project, so that I can use it later on to build more complex projects. However, there is already a problem with this simple app. In a template there is an `{{#each }}` block, but it's not rendering at all. I've spent hours trying to find the bug. Here is what I have so far:

I created the following collection in `TodoList/lib/collections.js`:

```
// security variables
UNAUTHORIZED = false;
AUTHORIZED = true;

TodoListItems = new Mongo.Collection("todolistitems");


TodoListItems.allow({
    insert: (user_id, doc) => {
        return AUTHORIZED;
    },

    remove: (user_id, doc) => {
        return AUTHORIZED;
    },

    update: (userId, doc) => {
        return AUTHORIZED;
    }
});
```

And the following `TodoList/client/routing.js`:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'BaseLayout'
});

Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('header', {
        to: 'header'
    });

    this.render('navbar', {
        to: 'navbar'
    });

    this.render('todolist_main', {
        to: 'main'
    });

    this.render('footer', {
        to: 'footer'
    });
});
```

Here is the `TodoList/client/templates/BaseLayout.html`:

```
<template name="BaseLayout">
    <head>
        <title>ToDo List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{> yield "header"}}
        {{> yield "navbar"}}
        {{> yield "main"}}
        {{> yield "footer"}}
    </body>
</template>
```

Here is the `TodoList/client/templates/todolist_main.html`:

```
<template name="todolist_main">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <div class="flexbox-container">
        {{#each todolistitems}}
            <div class="flexbox-item" id="todolist_item_{{_id}}">
                <p>{{short_text}}</p>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

To make the collection initially have some objects in it, I have the following code on the server side in `TodoList/server/server.js`:

```
// start up function that creates entries in the Websites databases.
Meteor.startup(() => {
    var first_user = Meteor.users.findOne();
    if(!first_user) {
        console.log('No users found, creating test user.');
        Accounts.createUser({
            username: 'test123',
            email: 'test123@test.com',
            password: 'test123',
            profile: {  // public attributes
                firstname: 'test',
                lastname: 'tester'
            }
        });
    }

    if (!TodoListItems.findOne()) {
        console.log("No todo list items yet. Creating starter data.");

        var tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
        var long_text = 'This is a test entry.';

        TodoListItems.insert({
            long_text: long_text,
            short_text: long_text.slice(0, 50) +  '...',
            priority: 5,
            status: 'open',
            due_date: tomorrow,
            category: 'test category',
            created_on: new Date()
            //TODO created_by ...
        });

        tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
        long_text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

        TodoListItems.insert({
            long_text: long_text,
            short_text: long_text.slice(0, 50) +  '...',
            priority: 5,
            status: 'open',
            due_date: tomorrow,
            category: 'test category',
            created_on: new Date()
            //TODO created_by ...
        });
    }
});
```

So when the app is run, there will be two todo list items inserted and the collection is defined in the `lib` folder, which means it should be run before everything else and the collection is neither only on the server nor only on the client, but available on both. When a user logs in, the template is supposed to render todo list items. However, the resulting HTML code when logged in is:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- tons of included scripts here-->
</head>
<body>
  <head>
        <title>ToDo List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="login-buttons-dropdown-align-" id="login-buttons">
    <div class="login-link-and-dropdown-list">
    <a id="login-name-link" class="login-link-text">
      test123 ▾
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </nav>
        <div class="flexbox-container">
        </div>
        <p>This is a footer.</p>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

(Don't ask me why there is two head and two body elements, this is how I learned to write the base layout in an online course, maybe it's wrong and part of the issue.)
As you can see, the todolist is not rendering, but only the part in the `{{#each todolistitems}}` is not rendering, as if there was no item and thus the loop is never entered. However, I already checked in the console of the browser, and there are items:

```
TodoListItems.findOne()
Object { _id: "RoeNmpKyaqQy9DGj8", long_text: "This is a test entry.", short_text: "This is a test entry....", priority: 5, status: "open", due_date: Date 2015-12-24T23:37:34.389Z, category: "test category", created_on: Date 2015-12-23T23:37:34.390Z }
```

At the moment I don't know what to try anymore. I already tried putting everything into one template and render that, but even then, as soon as something is in the each block, it doesn't render.

Where am I going wrong here? How can I make it render todo list items?

Answer (score 0):

If found the bug. I didn't know that I have to add helpers for collections used in an each block as well. The bug was simply, that I didn't write a helper for the template returning the collection like this:

```
Template.todolist_main.helpers({
    todolistitems: () => {
        if(Session.get('user_filter')) {
            return TodoListItems.find (
                {created_by: Session.get('user_filter')},
                {sort: {rating: -1, created_on: -1}}
            );
        }
        return TodoListItems.find (
            {},
            {
                sort: {rating: -1, created_on: -1},
                limit: 100
            }
        );
    }
});
```